# SNMP4J v2c Trap Send Very Slow

Tags: java, performance, snmp, snmp4j

I am using SNMP4J for sending SNMPv2 Trap. This java apps will run, send the trap and exit.

now i have a problem, whenever first round i run this apps, it execute very fast. after that, start from second round onward, it will took average more than 50 seconds to complete the snmp.send(pdu, comtarget);

Hope can get some idea from you guys

i attached my code and output below:

```
public void sendSnmpV2Trap(String message) {
    try {
        // Create Transport Mapping
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        TransportMapping transport = new DefaultUdpTransportMapping();
        transport.listen();
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long diff = end - start;
        LOGGER.debug("TransportMapping listening took "+ diff + " ms");

        start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        // Create Target
        CommunityTarget comtarget = new CommunityTarget();
        comtarget.setCommunity(new OctetString(community));
        comtarget.setVersion(SnmpConstants.version2c);
        comtarget.setAddress(new UdpAddress(ipAddress + "/" + port));
        comtarget.setRetries(2);
        comtarget.setTimeout(500);

        // Create PDU for V2
        PDU pdu = new PDU();

        // variable binding for Enterprise Specific objects, Severity (should be defined in MIB file)
        pdu.add(new VariableBinding(SnmpConstants.snmpTrapOID, new OctetString("1.2")));            
        pdu.add(new VariableBinding(new OID(trapOid), new OctetString(message)));
        pdu.setType(PDU.NOTIFICATION);
        end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        diff = end - start;
        LOGGER.debug("Create object took "+ diff + " ms");

        start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        // Send the PDU
        Snmp snmp = new Snmp(transport);            
        LOGGER.info("Sending V2 Trap to " + ipAddress + " on Port " + port+". Message="+ message);
        snmp.send(pdu, comtarget);
        snmp.close();
        end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        diff = end - start;
        LOGGER.debug("Send trap took "+ diff + " ms");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error("Error in Sending V2 Trap to " + ipAddress + " on Port " + port);
        LOGGER.error("Exception Message = " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

the output:

```
    [root@responder01 healthCheck]# java -jar healthChecker.jar --test
    2015-04-17 10:31:21 DEBUG SnmpJTrapSender:113 - TransportMapping listening took 19 ms
    2015-04-17 10:31:21 DEBUG SnmpJTrapSender:133 - Create object took 6 ms
    2015-04-17 10:31:21 INFO  SnmpJTrapSender:138 - Sending V2 Trap to 192.168.6.45 on Port 162. Message=testing on Apr 17, 2015 10:31:21 AM
    2015-04-17 10:31:21 DEBUG SnmpJTrapSender:143 - Send trap took 79 ms
    [root@responder01 healthCheck]# java -jar healthChecker.jar --test
    2015-04-17 10:31:24 DEBUG SnmpJTrapSender:113 - TransportMapping listening took 18 ms
    2015-04-17 10:31:24 DEBUG SnmpJTrapSender:133 - Create object took 8 ms
    2015-04-17 10:32:32 INFO  SnmpJTrapSender:138 - Sending V2 Trap to 192.168.6.45 on Port 162. Message=testing on Apr 17, 2015 10:31:23 AM
    2015-04-17 10:32:32 DEBUG SnmpJTrapSender:143 - Send trap took 68546 ms
```

Comment: Better than checking execution time here, can you check if the messages are recieved faily quickly at trap receiver.

Answer (score 0):

According to your output this code

```
    LOGGER.debug("Create object took "+ diff + " ms");

    start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    // Send the PDU
    Snmp snmp = new Snmp(transport);            
    LOGGER.info("Sending V2 Trap to " + ipAddress + " on Port " + port+". Message="+ message);
```

is taking the time.

There is nothing here that would take such amount of time, so maybe you whole system is crawling.

Comment: but during first round it is fast. always start with second round onward... it is slow. it is the way i terminate the session having problem?